# TreeView selected event is not working to bind treeview selected items in gridview using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, treeview

I have bind a TreeView using LINQ in entityframework. The tree generation code seems like below

```
protected void GenerateTree()
{
    trvMenu.Nodes.Clear();
    ReportColumnDefinationDA reportColumnDa = new ReportColumnDefinationDA(true);
    List<RB_Report_Column_Defination> listMenu = reportColumnDa.GetAllDefination().OrderBy(x => x.RB_ReportType.Name).ToList();
    if (listMenu != null && listMenu.Count > 0)
    {
        try
        {

            foreach (RB_Report_Column_Defination firstLevelItem in listMenu.GroupBy(i => i.Report_type).Select(g => g.First()))
            {
                TreeNode ParentNode = new TreeNode();

                ParentNode.Text = firstLevelItem.RB_ReportType.Name;
                ParentNode.Value = firstLevelItem.Report_type.ToString();
                ParentNode.ShowCheckBox = false;
                ParentNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;
                trvMenu.Nodes.Add(ParentNode);

                // Add Child Node 


                foreach (RB_Report_Column_Defination secondLevelItem in listMenu.Where(X => X.Report_type == firstLevelItem.Report_type))
                {
                    TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode();
                    childNode.Text = secondLevelItem.Column_Name;
                    childNode.Value = secondLevelItem.Id.ToString();
                    childNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;

                    Session["val"]=secondLevelItem.Id.ToString();
                    ParentNode.ChildNodes.Add(childNode);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.Message;
        }

    }

}
```

Now I want to bind the selected/checked nodes in a grid view, so I used

> trvMenu_SelectedNodeChanged

event to bind selected node datain the grid view  and the code is

```
 protected void trvMenu_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["val"]);
    ReportColumnDefinationDA reportDa = new ReportColumnDefinationDA(true);
    List<RB_Report_Column_Defination> definatons = new List<RB_Report_Column_Defination>();
    definatons = reportDa.GetAllDefinationListByID(id);
    gridRptDefination.DataSource = definatons;
    gridRptDefination.DataBind();
}
```

but the code is not working, what is wrong with my code? I also tried with another event

> trvMenu_TreeNodeCheckChanged

but still not working, the gridview is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

did you add this to treeview html markup?

```
OnSelectedNodeChanged="trvMenu_SelectedNodeChanged"
```

and change this lines

```
ParentNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;
childNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;
```

to

```
ParentNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Select;
childNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Select;
```

Comment: yes all mark up added but the change event is not working the gridview is still empty.